# Error with JAVADB at Netbeans

Tags: sql, netbeans, collation, string-comparison, javadb

I had try to delete a record at my database on JavaDB at Netbeans and it give me this error message

`Error code -1, SQL state 42818`

Delete command failed: Comparisons between 'LONG VARCHAR (UCS_BASIC)' and 'LONG VARCHAR (UCS_BASIC)' are not supported. Types must be comparable. String types must also have matching collation. If collation does not match, a possible solution is to cast operands to force them to the default collation (e.g. SELECT tablename FROM sys.systables WHERE CAST(tablename AS VARCHAR(128)) = 'T1')"

I don't know how to fix it!

Answer (score -1):

Please refer to the the chapter "Data type assignments and comparison, sorting, and ordering" in the Derby reference manual:

https://builds.apache.org/job/Derby-docs/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/trunk/out/ref/rrefsqlj58560.html